# failed to push some refs

Tags: git

В чем проблема? Публичный ключ настроил.

```
$ git push origin master
To https://github.com/merrymaker14/uploadca.git
! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to https://github.com/merrymaker14/uploadca.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushin
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

В репозитории на сервере есть изменения, которые появились там после того, как Вы склонировались. Скорее всего, кто-то уже в него запушил изменения. Чтобы не было конфликтов в будущем, система не дает вам запушить ваши изменения, пока вы не актуализируете у себя репозиторий.

Вам нужно вначале скачать изменения к себе локально:

```
git pull
```

В случае возникновения конфликтов - разрешить их, после чего система вам позволит выполнить `git push`.

Comment: @TimurMusharapov что именно сделали? Конфликт вы же так и не разрешили.

Comment: Ввел как команду git pull

Comment: @TimurMusharapov что написало после ввода git pull ?

Comment: То, что отписал в первом комментарии.

Comment: @TimurMusharapov у вас в первом коментарии написано что вы выполнили git push origin master, а вам нужно сначала выполнить git pull

Comment: Timur@home-pc MINGW64 /c/uploadcare (master)
$ git pull origin master
From https://github.com/merrymaker14/uploadca
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories

Comment: @TimurMusharapov попробуйте `git pull --allow-unrelated-histories`

Comment: Вначале помогло, но обнаружились конфликты, а в итоге: $ git pull origin master --allow-unrelated-histories
error: 'uploadcare-php' appears as both a file and as a directory
error: uploadcare-php: cannot drop to stage #0
error: Pull is not possible because you have unmerged files.
hint: Fix them up in the work tree, and then use 'git add/rm <file>'
hint: as appropriate to mark resolution and make a commit.
fatal: Exiting because of an unresolved conflict.

Comment: Можно как-то посмотреть, где остались конфликты?

Comment: Timur@home-pc MINGW64 /c/uploadca (master|MERGING)
$ git add .
error: unable to index file uploadcare-php
fatal: updating files failed

Comment: Вот за это я и не люблю конскольный гитхаб. Неудобный. Непонятный. Мне надо просто удалить много папок, пришлось скачать репозиторий, но как его залить так, чтобы при закачивании удалённые папки не замещались теми, которые там есть - та ещё задача. Очень тяжело, главное - бесполезно

Answer (score 2):

git push --force
Ваша проблема была из-за того, что кто-то внёс изменения в удалённый репозиторий, и вам в принудительном порядке предлагают загрузить к себе обновления (git pull)
Но с помощью верхней команды (git push --force) я даю понять, что я не хочу клонировать к себе обновленную на удалённом репозитории версию

Comment: опишите, пожалуйста, прямо в тексте вопроса (нажав [edit]), к каким последствиям приведёт ваша рекомендация, и какие организацонные вопросы надо решить, чтобы избежать таких последствий.

Comment: поправка: в тексте ответа, конечно.

Answer (score 1):

Также возможно причиной может быть - то что файлы все еще используються другой программой.
если у вас просто

> error: failed to push some refs to 'https://gitlab.com/...'

Answer (score 1):

Добавлю для истории, такое может быть, если еще нечего пушить. С чистым репозиторием, вместо первого коммита попробвать сделать пуш

Answer (score 0):

Возникла такая проблема только что на gitlab с новым проектом. Решил таким методом:
 1. Создал readme файл на самом сайте в master
 2. сделал git clone
 3. создал ветку develop
 4. перекинул проект в текущий репозиторий
 5. запушил develop