# Ошибка git push

Tags: git, git-push

я начал изучать git и когда я пушу у меня выходит ошибка:

```
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)

error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/Nursultanno/AppForAndroid'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Comment: ну тут же все написано. в репозитории есть коммиты, которых нету в локальном проекте. для этого надо сначала спулить удаленный репозиторий, и только потом пушить изменения. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/574294/failed-to-push-some-refs

Comment: @dasauser написаное же надо прочитать. А читать-то некогда - надо срочно бежать в интернет спрашивать!

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [failed to push some refs](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/574294/failed-to-push-some-refs)

Answer (score 0):

Так как вы изучать только начали Git, то могу предположить что вы клонировали на локальную машину. После начали что то править уже через браузер на удаленном Github. Параллельно на локальной машине начали свои правки делать и при попытки пуша выскочила ошибка. 
Сделайте на локальной машине сначала Pull и уже потом править. 
Вообще в будущем лучше заранее привыкать пулить перед тем как править что то, когда будете работать в команде всегда нужно иметь локально актуальную версию.

Comment: Спасибо, сработало